# Log.d is not working when filtering logcat

Tags: android, filter, logcat, android-logcat

My verbose logcat is not working for

```
Log.d("b","Hi stack.");
```

because I am filtering logcat with gc.uploaderimager(my package name). If I don't filter the logcat with my package name logcat is being too fast, excessive messages.

1 week ago, there was no problem and I remember that I did not any filtering and no excessive messages. What did happen 1 week ago? I couldn't understand.

Now, I can **not** see log messages if **do**  filtering.

My logcat is too fast and **not** readable if do **not** filtering.

Then what is the solution?

```
package gc.uploaderimager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("b","Hi stack.");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you filter the logcat? Are you doing this from the command line with `adb logcat` or are you using the Android Monitor window in Android Studio?

Comment: like this:
http://i.hizliresim.com/gXmmLQ.png

Comment: What happens if you type "stack" in the filter field?

Comment: It is shown.
http://i.hizliresim.com/rEPP8N.png

Comment: If I do not filter, it shows excessive messages.

Comment: I've had this problem a few times; I believe it's a bug in Android Studio. I usually just re-build+run the app, and it will correctly detect the app again.

Comment: @AndrewSun with filtering or without filtering by package name?

Comment: @serkanstack You shouldn't have to type your package name, Android Studio automatically filters everything that's not coming from your app.

Comment: Notice that "Hi, stack" is shown in the second screen shot. When Android Studio is working correctly, you should be able to select your app's package name from the drop down box that currently says "No Debuggable Application". This will show just the messages which your app logs.

Comment: The filter field is available for additional filtering than what Android Studio should do automatically, but often doesn't do correctly.

Comment: @AndrewSun It is not working for me, I tried to rebuild + run but it is same

Comment: Disable and enable your adb integration inside tools.

Comment: See my answer below for additional suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Monitor view in Android Studio is a little flaky from my experience. Your app's package name should appear in the combo box where it currently says "No Debuggable Applications". You should restart adb by typing `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` from the command line. (You may need to `cd` to the `platform-tools` directory in your Android SDK installation or add this directory to `PATH` in your operating system configuration.) You might also need to restart Android Studio after doing this.

Since Android Studio has problems with viewing logcat, many developers use third-party tools instead. [pidcat](https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat) from Jake Wharton is one popular choice.

**Addendum:**

Part of the problem is that your log output doesn't include the package name in the line of output:

```
11-05 23:28:58.554 28331-28331/? D/b: Hi stack.
```

The `?` should be your package name instead. In fact all of the lines in your output has this `?` where a package name should be. I don't know the exact cause, but there are some things that I can think of checking:

1. Be sure that USB Debugging is enabled on your phone.
2. Restart adb as explained above. You can also try the Restart button in the left-hand toolbar in the Android Monitor window in Android Studio.

Comment: Also, his package name should be visible in the logcat as much as I remember

Comment: What are you using? pidcat? Do you suggest me? if yes I will not waste time with this problem no longer.

Comment: @serkanstack I usually muddle with Android Studio as best as I can.

Comment: I am beginner. Do you suggest this script for beginner?

Comment: @serkanstack I have added a few more suggestions to my answer. `pidcat` is definitely worth checking out no matter your skill level.

Comment: You are wonderful ! I solved by restarting adb from command line. I do not have to filter anymore.